# Android RSS Parse: get image thumbnail

Tags: android, rss, thumbnails, rss-reader

I am trying to make a news reader for Android, but I am no able to find out how to parse the thumbnail from each rss item. Do I have to pase every url of the thumbnail and than save them to use them or can I just use them with the url? This is the code for the feed

```
public class RssFeed implements Parcelable {`

    private String title;
    private String link;
    private String description;
    private String language;
    private ArrayList<RssItem> rssItems;

    public RssFeed() {
        rssItems = new ArrayList<RssItem>();
    }

    public RssFeed(Parcel source) {

        Bundle data = source.readBundle();
        title = data.getString("title");
        link = data.getString("link");
        description = data.getString("description");
        language = data.getString("language");
        rssItems = data.getParcelableArrayList("rssItems");

    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putString("title", title);
        data.putString("link", link);
        data.putString("description", description);
        data.putString("language", language);
        data.putParcelableArrayList("rssItems", rssItems);
        dest.writeBundle(data);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<RssFeed> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<RssFeed>() {
        public RssFeed createFromParcel(Parcel data) {
            return new RssFeed(data);
        }
        public RssFeed[] newArray(int size) {
            return new RssFeed[size];
        }
    };
```

and this is the Rss reader: (I also created an object RssItem which stores the values).

```
public class RssReader {

    public static RssFeed read(URL url) throws SAXException, IOException {

        return read(url.openStream());

    }

    public static RssFeed read(InputStream stream) throws SAXException, IOException {

        try {

            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader = parser.getXMLReader();
            RssHandler handler = new RssHandler();
            InputSource input = new InputSource(stream);

            reader.setContentHandler(handler);
            reader.parse(input);

            return handler.getResult();

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            throw new SAXException();
        }

    }

    public static RssFeed read(String source) throws SAXException, IOException {
        return read(new ByteArrayInputStream(source.getBytes()));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by parsing the URL. I guess you have the entire URL of the thumbnail.

If you have the URL of the thumbnail then I guess you can use any image downloading and caching libraries like [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) and [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). They are easy to use and do all the heavy lifting for you when you want to work with images in Android.

I have used Picasso and it works as advertised. Though, I would love to give Glide a try too owing to what I have heard in developer circles.

Note : There maybe other libraries that can help you with the same, so maybe have a look at whats out there and what works for you!

Hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: ok thank you but my problem is that i dont know how to get the url!

Comment: The url must be a part of the RssItem model, right? Since you get ArrayList of RssItem objects, you can simply use it from there! I will need to see some more code, if this does not make sense to you to explain better maybe.